# how do I return key, value of nested key and value of second nested value

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I'm sure there must be a relatively easy way to do this but I'm either missing it completely or simply can't seem to grasp it. I'm usually fairly competent at finding the answer I need but I'm having no luck. Hoping someone will be able to help.

If I have the below dictionary how do I print (or return) The key, a value from a set of the nested values, and a value from the second nested set?

```
people = {
        "123": {
            "name": "Danny",
            "age": 100,
            "animal": "cat",
            "last_action": {
                "status": "Offline",
                "timestamp": 1664651202,
                "relative": "50 minutes ago"
            },
            "status": {
                "description": "Okay",
                "details": "",
                "state": "Okay",
                "color": "green",
                "until": 0
            },
            "number": "Six"
        },
        "456": {
            "name": "Suzy",
            "age": 42,
            "animal": dog,
            "last_action": {
                "status": "Offline",
                "timestamp": 1664636683,
                "relative": "4 hours ago"
            },
            "status": {
                "description": "Not Okay",
                "details": "",
                "state": "Okay",
                "color": "green",
                "until": 0
            },
            "number": "Twelve"
        },"789": {
            "name": "Chris",
            "age": 23,
            "animal": "horse",
            "last_action": {
                "status": "Offline",
                "timestamp": 1664636683,
                "relative": "4 hours ago"
            },
            "status": {
                "description": "Okay",
                "details": "",
                "state": "Okay",
                "color": "green",
                "until": 0
            },
            "number": "Two"
        }
```

Specifically, in the above I want to print (or assign to a variable for other uses) the below;

```
123 Danny Okay
456 Suzy Not Okay
789 Chris Okay
```

I **KNOW** there must be a for loop for this and have tried several combinations of

```
key for key in people.items()
```

```
key for value in.....
```

I've also tried things along the lines of

```
numbers = people.keys()
```

and then using the numbers variable in the for loop as well.

I'm sorry I'm doing such a poor job of explaining the solutions I've tried but I can't access my current version at the moment and I've re-written it so many times I no longer remember them all.

It's also complicated (to me anyway) by the fact that I need the three elements as variables, so rather than just `789 Chris Okay` I want `{numbers}{name}{status}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension over `people.items()`:

```py
res = [ f'{k} {v["name"]} {v["status"]["description"]}' for k, v in people.items() ]
```

Output:

```
['123 Danny Okay', '456 Suzy Not Okay', '789 Chris Okay']
```

Alternatively you could just iterate in a `for` loop:

```
for k, v in people.items():
    status = f'{k} {v["name"]} {v["status"]["description"]}'
    print(status)   # or do something else with it
```

Output:

```
123 Danny Okay
456 Suzy Not Okay
789 Chris Okay
```

Or, if you want a set of discrete variables:

```py
number, name, status = map(list, zip(*[ (k, v["name"], v["status"]["description"]) for k, v in people.items() ]))
number
# ['123', '456', '789']
name
# ['Danny', 'Suzy', 'Chris']
status
# ['Okay', 'Not Okay', 'Okay']
```

Or in the `for` loop:

```py
numbers = people.keys()
for number in numbers:
    name = people[number]['name']
    status = people[number]['status']['description']
    print(f'{number} {name} {status}')   # or do something else with them
```

Output:

```
123 Danny Okay
456 Suzy Not Okay
789 Chris Okay
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can convert these into lists for each person, or into strings.

```
res = []

numbers = people.keys()
for inner in numbers:
  name = people[inner]["name"]
  status = people[inner]["status"]["description"]
  res.append(inner)
  res.append(name)
  res.append(status)

# Save result as lists for each person

danny = res[0:3]
suzy = res[3:6]
chris = res[6:9]

print(danny)
print(suzy)
print(chris)

# Output
# ['123', 'Danny', 'Okay']
# ['456', 'Suzy', 'Not Okay']
# ['789', 'Chris', 'Okay']

# Converts list results into strings for each person

danny_str = " ".join(danny)
suzy_str = " ".join(suzy)
chris_str = " ".join(chris)

print(danny_str)
print(suzy_str)
print(chris_str)

# Output
# 123 Danny Okay
# 456 Suzy Not Okay
# 789 Chris Okay
```

Comment: this will also be very useful, thank you so much!